# Is it permitted to pray in underclothes that one slept in (underwear, t shirt) if outer clothes changed?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, clothing, sleep

I hear there is an inyan not to pray in clothes that one slept in. I also heard the qualification that this is only for clothes meant for sleeping. (I don't have sources)

Would something like boxers and undershirt count under this rule?

For example, you are away for shabbat, but only have one undershirt. You sleep in it, but can't change it the next day. Is is better not to wear it to tefillah?

Comment: Joshc, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the interesting question. Please note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice: treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Seems to be no mekor

Comment: Except for Kitzur Shulchan Aruch maybe,but the minhag is not to be concerned with sleeping in clothes.

Comment: http://www.kitzur.net/main.php?siman=71 halacha 5

Answer (score 1):

I learnt that as soon as our eyes open from sleeping that Modeh Ani is declared. 
This would imply that a person would immediately start praying in the very clothes that they had slept in.

Comment: Different kinds of prayer may have different rules.

Comment: w0lf, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for sharing this insight! I hope you'll look around the site and find other information that interests you, perhaps including our 583 other [tag:tefilla] questions.

Comment: Especially since modeh aNi does not contain gods name